# Developing Golang Package, cannot use relative path

Tags: import, go, package

I'm trying to develop a simple golang package

let's say its name is "Hello", the directory structure is like below

```
hello
   games
   game-utils
```

then in hello.go (the main code) I have these:

```
import (
    gameUtils "./game-utils"
    "./games"
)
```

ok this worked well until I push to remote repo(e.g github.com) and try to use `go get` to install it. The problem was with the import path, I must change it to

```
import (
    gameUtils "github.com/user/hello/game-utils"
    "github.com/user/hello/games"
)
```

the question is, everytime I develop the package I cannot import using `"github.com/user/hello/game-utils"` because obviously I wouldn't have pushed it to the remote repo, I need to import it using `"./game-utils"`.

Is there any elegant way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

You should always import it using:

```
import "github.com/user/hello/game-utils"
```

This is because of how the go tool works. It will look for it on the local machine in the directory: `"GOPATH/src/github.com/user/hello/game-utils"`. As @JimB points out, the compiler always works with the local sources and the import paths are relative to `GOPATH/src`.

The `go get` tool is the only one that looks for the sources on the internet. After getting them, it downloads them to `"GOPATH/src/IMPORT_PATH"` so the compiler and the other tools can now see them in their local structure.

If you are creating a new project you should respect the same directory structure. If you are planning to upload your code to github then create manually the folder `"GOPATH/src/github.com/YOUR-GITHUB-USER/PROYECT-NAME"` and then initialize your git repo in there. (This works at least on `git`, `hg`, `svn` and `github`, `bitbucket` and `google code`)

Comment: @Topo
Hi thanks for quick response, so to sum it up, 
I just need to:
1. `import gameUtils "github.com/user/hello/game-utils"` 
2. install using `go install github.com/user/hello`
3. cd to the repo `$GOPATH/src/github....` 
4. then start developing (testing, committing, bla bla) there?

Comment: @sendyhalim You are welcome. You are mostly correct. A detail on number 2. get the source with go get (not go install). And if I'm going to modify the code that I'm downloading with ´go get´, I prefer to create the directory structure myself and get the code with ´git clone´, in my experience this can help avoid some git repo configuring later.

Comment: @Topo ok! Haha. Anw, if I haven't pushed any code yet, then the only way is to create the dir('$GOPATH/src/user/hello') manually and develop there right?